# Weblogic server throwing Connection refused error

Tags: weblogic-10.x

When i am trying to start my weblogic 10.3.5 i am getting the below exception both the server and eclipse are on same system and using windiows

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.connect.SocketTransportService$2.run(SocketTransportService.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues causing  "Connection refused"

1. Are you starting wl on windows or .... Firewall?
2. Did you start the admin console?
   Please open

   ```
   http://localhost:7001/console
   ```
3. Please post the content of wl log

Answer (score 1):

1) First start your weblogic server, using the file `startWebLogic.cmd` located in
  `Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin`.

2) A cmd window will be opened and wait until this comes "SOA accepting requests"  in the cmd window.

3) Now type the URL `http://localhost:7001/console` in the browser to get the weblogic server page.